# Setting response header parameters and query parameters

Tags: client-server, jetty

I am using javax.ws.rs.core.Response.

I want to send a response messeage with header parameters (String) and a query parameters (String). How can i define this in my response?

Now i am using:

```
return     Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(cur_request.getBody()).header("Location", "aaa").build();
```

Not sure what it means.
In what format should the answer sent? for example if my header paramter is "Content-Type=application/xml", how can i pass this in my response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .header() to pass them or put then in the response entity

Comment: .header is defined with 2 parameters: header("a","b"), what is a and what is b? as i see it i only need one string like "Content-Type=application/xml"

Comment: The two param is just the two value separate by equal character so header("Content-Type", "application/xml") and you can pass your arguments like header("my_property", "my_value")